# Wordpress: the_excerpt not working

Tags: wordpress

I recently updated wordpress and now all content is outputting for this module, except "the_excerpt()"

```
<?php

function blog_feed_content(){
  ?>
  <ul id="blog_list" class="jscroll">
            <?php
            global $post;
            $args = array('category' => 4 );
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <li class="post clearfix" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <div class="post-content clearfix">
                        <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F Y') ?></div>
                        <div class="post-text">
                             <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>


  <?php
}

function widget_blog_feed($args){
  extract($args);
  echo $before_widget;
  echo $before_title;?>Blog Feed<?php echo $after_title;
  blog_feed_content();
  echo $after_widget;
}

function init_blog_feed() {
  register_sidebar_widget(__('blog_widget'), 'widget_blog_feed');
}
add_action("plugins_loaded", "init_blog_feed");
?>
```

Why on earth isn't it outputting this one piece of content?

YOU'RE ALL AWESOME. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`setup_postdata` is not exactly the same as using a normal `WP_Query` with `the_post()` so not all template tags work as expected with this method of displaying posts.

You should rewrite the code to use a custom `WP_Query` and traditional Loop rather than using a `foreach` to iterate through post objects.

Something like:

```
$myposts = new WP_Query('cat=4');
if( $myposts->have_posts() ) : while( $myposts->have_posts() ) : $myposts->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="post clearfix" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="post-content clearfix">
            <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <div class="post-date"><?php the_time('F Y') ?></div>
            <div class="post-text">
                 <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
   </li>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query;
endif; ?>
```

That should point you in the right direction.  If you are set on sticking with the `foreach` and `get_posts` method you could always use some simple string functions (i.e. `substr()` to truncate a little excerpt from the `post_content` property of the `$post` object, like replacing the `<?php the_content(); ?>` line with:

```
<?php echo substr($post->the_content, 0, 80); // displays first 80 chars of post ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should define id.

```
<?php echo get_the_excerpt($post->ID); ?
```